# How to all left and right margins to Safe Area in iOS?

Tags: ios

I have two Stack Views that are constrained to start from a Safe Area.

[image]

I want to add some space between them and the beginning of the screen.

Instead of adding margin values to each Stack View, can I make Safe Area smaller to move all elements? Or it is possible to add left padding to Safe Area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set 'additionalSafeAreaInsets' property of the UIViewController to set safe area insets.

```
self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 60, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to set it somewhere in design builder interface?